# Locking iPhone in a Certain Time Zone

Tags: iphone, timezone

I live in a town that is right on a Time Zone border (it actually cuts right through the town).  The entire town itself is on Central Time, but depending on which cell tower you hit, my iPhone will either display Eastern Time or Central Time, and it's not exactly obvious which one it is unless you're paying close attention.

Is there a way to lock the phone into a specified Time Zone, or at least enable the Time Zone to show alongside the time (e.g.: 16:15 CST)?

Comment: Have you tried to disable automatic date & time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what town?

Comment: @MattJohnson it's in Adair Co, KY

Comment: I see. So the town straddles both sides of the county line, which is also the time zone boundary, so the town picks one side or the other at the local level?  Very interesting indeed!  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the automatic setting of date/time in Settings->General->Date & Time. Of course this also means that you have to manually set the time if you actually move to a different time zone on purpose.

Comment: Perfect!  That's what I was looking for!  Thanks!  I'll accept when it lets me :)

Comment: Another caveat is that your phone time will most likely drift a few seconds each day/week.  One time, with my phone set to manually update the time, I noticed that it had lost 2-3 minutes.  Turning on the automatic setting fixed the lag.